# Recursive model_json_schema in pydantic v2

Tags: python, pydantic

I'm using pydantic to create the schema for the usage with https://github.com/json-editor/json-editor

I'm using a "main" class to select a method as follows:

```py
class Analysis(BaseModel):
    method: methods = Field(
        ..., description="Analysis method", discriminator="method"
    )
```

I'd like to make changes to the json schema in each of the `methods`.
My naive approach was, to override `model_json_schema` as follows:

```py
class Properties1D(BaseModel):
    method: t.Literal["Properties1D"] = "Properties1D"

    value: str = "a"
   
    @classmethod
    def model_json_schema(cls, *args, **kwargs) -> dict[str, t.Any]:
        schema = super().model_json_schema(*args, **kwargs)
        schema["properties"]["value"]["enum"] = ["a", "b", "c"]
        return schema

methods = t.Union[Properties1D, None]
```

but unfortunately, the `model_json_schema` is not being used, when I run `Analysis.model_json_schema()`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the PyDantic developers I could resolve this (see https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/7789)

One can use the `ConfigDict(json_schema_extra=...)` with a function to modify the scheme of the class in a way, that it is correctly displayed when calling the `model_json_schema` on the surrounding class.

Something like

```py
class Properties1D(BaseModel):
    method: t.Literal["Properties1D"] = "Properties1D"
    value: str = "a"

    model_config = ConfigDict(json_schema_extra={"some_field": "properties 1d val"})
```